# Verify an inequality using induction: $\frac1{2n}\le \frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(2n-1)}{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdots(2n)}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, proof-explanation, solution-verification

How can I verify this inequality by using induction?

$$\frac1{2n}\le \frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(2n-1)}{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdots(2n)}$$

I understand the principle of induction, but I'm struggling with how my teacher is solving this problem. I Highlighted the area I'm stuck at In the solution - why are we able to take $1/2k$ and see if its less than the left side of our inducted hypothesis? (view the highlighted part of the photo)

Any suggestions would be great - I really don't understand how to solve this problem. If I could get a step by step walk through of this proof with side notes, I'd be very grateful

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In this screenshot from your image call the LHS and RHS of the first inequality (which is a consequence of the induction hypothesis) $B$ and $C$ respectively. The first inequality is stating that $\boxed{B\le C}$.

> Call the LHS of the second inequality, marked in yellow by you, to be $A$.

You want to prove $A\le C$, and you have already proved $B\le C$ (mentioned in the first block above), so 
 if you can prove $A\le B$, then you can combine the consequence of the first inequality, i.e $\boxed{B\le C}$ with $A\le B$ to get $$A\le B \le C \implies A \le C$$ which would prove the claim. So we *want to prove* (as written by your teacher) that $A\le B$.

[image]

Comment: I forgot to add - How did my professor get the inequality A? How/why is it set up like that?

Comment: @IsabelleKreienbrink because $A$ is precisely the LHS of the statement mentioned in problem $13$, with $n$ replaced by $k$. That's what you do for induction, check a base case, which is in this case $n=1$, assume it to be true for natural numbers $1,2,3,\cdots,k-1$ (for some $k$), rewrite the statement to be proved - with $n$ replaced by $k-1$ ((this is the induction hypothesis)) and then try to prove the statement with $n$ replaced by $k$, with the help of the induction hypothesis.

Comment: And you want to prove $A\le C$, but you already have got something lesser than or equal to $C$ which is $B$, **so if you can prove that $A$ is lesser than that something ($B$), then $A$ would obviously be lesser than or equal to $C$** - This is why the prof. wants to show $A\le B$.

Comment: Oh I see! So we have an inequality we are trying to prove (call the left side a). We create an inductive hypothesis from it, let the left side of it be called b, and the right side will be C. Since we assume in our hypothesis that B<C all there is left to do is prove A<B, and we can reach our conclusion - that A<C - right? (you can do this for the right hand side as well but I didn't describe that process)

Comment: Yes, you are right. You could proceed in a similar way starting with $A\le B$ and prove $B\le C$ so that you can combine them to get the desired result $A\le C$.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense now - thank you so much

Comment: One more question actually - why do we multiply both sides of the inductive hypothesis by 2k-1/2k?

Comment: Look at the RHS of the original statement with $n$ replaced by $k-1$ and look at the RHS of the original statement with $n$ replaced by $k$. The first differs from the second by a factor of $\dfrac{2k-1}{2k}$.

Comment: I see now that they do differ, but What does multiplying by those factors do to the inductive hypothesis? why is that necessary?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113011/discussion-between-fawkes4494d3-and-isabelle-kreienbrink).

Answer (score 1):

Your teacher simply uses transitivity of inequalities:

To simplify the notations, I'll use double factorials.

The inductive hypothesis is that $\;\dfrac1{2(k-1)}\le \dfrac{(2k-3)!!}{(2k-2)!!}$, and he/she wants to deduce that
$$\dfrac1{2k}\le \dfrac{(2k-1)!!}{(2k)!!}.$$

Now, observing that $\; \dfrac{(2k-1)!!}{(2k)!!}= \dfrac{(2k-3)!!}{(2 k-2)!!}\cdot\dfrac{2k-1}{2k}$, we deduce from the inductive hypothesis that
$$\dfrac{(2k-1)!!}{(2k)!!}\ge\frac1{2k-2}\cdot \frac{2k-1}{2k}=\frac1{2k}\cdot \underbrace{\frac{2k-1}{2k-2}}_{{}>1}>\frac1{2k}.$$

Comment: why do we multiply both sides of the inductive hypothesis by 2k-1/2k?

Comment: Because of the double factorials: $(2k)!!=2k(2k-2)(2k-4)\dotsm 4\cdot2=2k\times (2k-2)!!$ and $(2k-1)!!=(2k-1)(2k-3)(2k-5)\dotsm 3\cdot 1=(2k-1)\times (2k-3)!!$

Comment: Im more so just asking about the concept: what's the point of doing that step?

Comment: I'm not sure I see what you mean. We need to make the step $k-1 \to k$. So we have to express the inequality at step $k$ in terms of the inequality at step $k-1$.